Why does this unoptimized build of a loop incrementing a counter run 4x faster on Zen 5 than recent Intel (Raptor Lake)?
The problem is that this code takes 4 times longer to run on my machine than on my friend's when target is set to a big number and I want to understand why.
void work(){
    for(long long i = 0; i < target; i++)
        current++;
}

My cpu:
Intel i9 13900k (Raptor Lake)
His cpu:
AMD Ryzen 9 9950X (Zen 5)
We have the same ram:
G.SKILL Ripjaws S5 Series 64GB (2 x 32GB) 288-Pin PC RAM DDR5 5600 (Neither of us turbo'd to 5600)
We disabled the compiler's optimization before we compiled the program from visual studio for the sake of benchmarking.
What could the possible reasons be for the huge difference in execution time even though our CPU's share similar clock speeds?
I expected the difference in execution time to be much smaller than it ended up being. It took about 15 seconds on his machine, and 60 seconds on mine. Here is the full source code of the test benchmark program we made.
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>


static long long target  = 5e10,
                 current = 0;


void work();


int main(){
    char delay;

    std::cin >> delay;

    float startTick    = clock();
    work();
    float ticksTaken   = (clock() - startTick),
          secondsTaken = ticksTaken/CLOCKS_PER_SEC,
          msTaken       = secondsTaken * 1e3;

    std::cout << "msTaken:    " << msTaken    << " ms"    << std::endl;

    std::cin >> delay;

    return 0;
}


void work(){
    for(long long i = 0; i < target; i++)
        current++;

    std::cout << current << std::endl;
}


Are you using the same versions of visual studio? Are you running the code in the debugger? I'm general the performance of unoptimised code is fairly meaningless

With optimization disabled current and i will be stored/reloaded every iteration, so the bottleneck is store-forwarding latency. Zen 5 does that with zero latency. I thought Golden Cove cores (the P-cores in your Raptor Lake) were also supposed to be able to do that (https://chipsandcheese.com/2023/03/12/a-peek-at-sapphire-rapids). Maybe your benchmark ran on an E-core? But running that long, the OS should have migrated it to a P-core in a small fraction of the run time.

https://agner.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=41 is about the zero-latency store-forwarding feature in Zen 2.  Just for the record, benchmarking with -O0 is nonsense as it creates bottlenecks different from those you'd find if you compiled normally. Why does clang produce inefficient asm with -O0 (for this simple floating point sum)? / Idiomatic way of performance evaluation? / How can I optimize these loops (with compiler optimization disabled)?

Can you post the disassembly for work() from the executable you used?  (Assuming what you've told us is correct, the answer is definitely going to be CPU-microarchitecture details, almost certainly store-forwarding latency.  If you're not interested in that level of detail of "why", then just read the "idiomatic ..." Q&A about how benchmarking is hard, but disabling optimization is worse.)

What's the relative performance of a simpler loop that only increments one variable (a loop counter like i), not two?  (Still with optimization disabled.)

The only way to know for sure is to take a look at the assembly code generated for the work loop on each machine. Benchmarking unoptimised code can give very misleading results. Also do at least 5 timings the first one will be affected by warmup. Are you sure that both machines have full spec fast memory and identical compiler versions and options? Godbolt suggests that identical code is generated for AMD & Intel in this instance.

Benchmarking unoptimised builds is like racing cars with the shift stick fixed to the first gear.

I'm going to disagree with the prevailing opinion here that benchmarking unoptimized code is nonsense. It doesn't give a realistic picture of the performance of the code but you don't care about that anyway, you're comparing CPUs. And this compares some aspects of those CPUs. It's a bit of an unusual comparison, and at this point I'm not entirely sure what is being compared (the usual suspect is memory renaming, but both CPUs should have been capable of it) but it's not an inherently invalid comparison.

And in any case it doesn't even matter whether the benchmark is nonsense or not, it had an unexpected result that deserves an explanation other than "it's nonsense" - the amount of sense the benchmark makes is not detected by the CPUs and used as a reason to run it in an unexpected amount of time. There is some real mechanism causing this.

@user555045: Exactly, that's why I approved this question from the staging ground.  The benchmark isn't useful for comparing performance of C++ programs in general or C++ loops like this in particular.  But the resulting machine code from compiling it this way has a bottleneck that different microarchitectures handle quite differently.  We've had similar "why" questions in the past such as Adding a redundant assignment speeds up code when compiled without optimization where a different store-forwarding detail was the answer.

So it's an interesting [cpu-architecture] question, not an interesting [c++] question.  (Except insofar as the answer is relevant to C++ programs that have objects compilers fail to optimize into registers, e.g. because of possible pointer aliasing.)

As said "Unoptimized" is meaningless, just test the optimized code! That being said the architecture of the processor can make a huge difference (even between generations of CPUs from the same vendor). If you want answers you will have to use a profiler. Watch this : Unlocking Modern CPU Power - Next-Gen C++ Optimization Techniques - Fedor G Pikus - C++Now 2024 and it might give you some insights too.

Assigning the result of clock() to a float may lose precision, as float doesn't have enough bits to represent all 32-bit integer clock_t values. I think the error would be at most 2 seconds, but better change it to double if you want some confidence in those numbers. Do the times match what you observe with a stopwatch?

You say both CPUs have similar rated clock speeds, but is that the speed they are both actually running at? Have you ruled out throttling due to power saving modes or high temperature? Are the systems otherwise idle (no background tasks using significant CPU time)?

Note the RAM speed is probably irrelevant. This function is tiny and all the action will be taking place within L1 cache.

having IOs (write on cout) in the work function makes the measurment completely biased, you very likely measure the speed of your console...

@PeterCordes From what I could tell while looking at task manager and HWiNFO during running the program, it seemed very clear that the program was running on a P-core. Also, thank you for approving this post from the staging grounds because these answers are all extremely informative.
Thanks to everybody who is commenting. Seems like differences in CPU architecture is likely the culprit. Specifically store-forwarding latency.

@user555045 "you're comparing CPUs" Doing meaningless work they are not necessarily optimised for. So one CPU is faster than another CPU at this kind of work. So what? Is this kind of work going to have a significant impact in a real world scenario? Show that scenario then.

@n.m.couldbeanAI if we wanted to (intentionally) measure the memory-renaming capabilities or store-to-load-forwarding latency of a CPU, the work would be meaningless as well, as is the case with essentially any such experiment. It doesn't matter. The result of the experiment is meaningful and interpretable. A "real world scenario" would not be suitable for such an experiment, with its performance being based on a weighted average of a thousand effects, with unknown weights. OPs code is not exactly a "good experiment", but may accidentally reveal something anyway.

@OznOg: the cout isn't inside the loop, and the iteration count is high enough that the time for a single cout is negligible. Yes, it adds a little time, but certainly doesn't explain a 45 second discrepancy.

@n.m.couldbeanAI Although the compiler code generation is poor for debugging modes with lots of extra read/write/read this speed difference has real world implications if code under development and being debugged will typically run 4x faster on an AMD platform than on Intel. The AMD time of 15s given above is actually faster than my i5-12600 can run fully optimised code (~21s). Is the AMD hardware capable of pretending to have more than one physical AX register?

@MartinBrown On my machine a fully optimized build runs for 0.144 ms, and an unoptimised one takes 82 s. 21 s looks very wrong to me. There should be no loop. Can you show the assembly?

@n.m.couldbeanAI Obviously that original code is optimised into oblivion ~1ms. I took the precaution of substituting an expression just complex enough to fox the optimiser (otherwise it loads a constant). I settled for current = (current >> 1) + i; as something that the optimiser would not be able to see through.  I know that expression could in principle overflow but starting from 0 it would take about 50 years to do so. It looks to me like the AMD CPU has some additional logic that enables it to be nearly as fast as an optimised loop by working only with the register contents.

@user555045 You should work that up into an answer! Zen memory renaming article you linked to on Agner's blog looks to me like it could explain exactly what we are seeing here. Zero latency access to a few heavily used memory addresses in a loop. Next question is does it also hold for floating point or only for GPregs (as he implies).

@MartinBrown "AMD CPU has some additional logic that enables it to be nearly as fast as an optimised loop by working only with the register contents" It could be the case. Effectively you would have a very small but very fast cache, as fast as the registers. I wonder how an optimized build on the AMD compares.

@n.m.couldbeanAI "still doesn't touch any memory in the loop" That is true of the compiler optimised loop on Intel or AMD - the big surprise is that the unoptimised loop in debug mode runs faster on the latest Ryzens than the optimised code does on my Intel 12600 (despite all the supufluous loads and stores)..

@MartinBrown yeah I already figured it out.
